# Why adding some port to IP address redirect to another IP?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port

I have a ubuntu server inside a router. And I have setup a DDNS (for example, example.com is the domain name) to point to my dynamic IP. The port 22 is forwarding to port 22 of ubuntu server, configed in router.

When I ping the domain name without any port (example.com), it points to the right ip address. but when I appending a port to the domain name (like example.com:22), it redirect to another IP address.

what's the matter?

Comment: You put the server inside the router?

Answer (score 4):

The [ping command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) utilizes the ICMP protocol, which does not have a concept of ports like the TCP and UDP protocols do.

You would probably be best served by picking up a book on basic networking concepts, particularly one that touches on the topic of common network protocols and what their differences are.

Answer (score 2):

Ping doesn't use TCP/UDP, so it has no concept of ports.